# testing form fields as a shadow dom elements with react testing-library and jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

We have our own web component and using the same with react component as generic-component. I am trying to test those **custom elements** which are created inside the shadow dom for our form-fields.
Now there are multiple input fields in my form. I am only able to access one but not others i.e only one field. I am using react-hook-form to handle the form stimulation.

I tried the below query and looped over each input to get the element

```
const customInput = document.querySelectorAll("hds-input")
customInput.shadowRoot.querySelector("input[name='mapName']")
```

```
  it("check form input fields with dummy values", async () => {
    render(<Order3DMaps />);
    const form = document.querySelector("form");
    expect(form).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(screen.getByText("Basic Information")).toBeInTheDocument();
    //get the field and add use input value
    const hdsInput = document.querySelectorAll("hds-input");
    hdsInput.forEach((element) => {
      const mapName = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("input[name='mapName']");
      const rawDataSiteName = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("input[name='rawDataSiteName']"); 
      userEvent.type(mapName, "testmapname");
      const organizationId = element.querySelector(
        "input[name='organizationId']"
      );
      expect(organizationId).toBeDisabled();
    });
```

In the above test case **rawDataSiteName** is always null. However, when I debug in the browser console and see the dom element, it's present but not accessible while writing a test case.

My idea here is to get the element and do **userEvent** like type and click on form fields to cover the unit testing. However, after spending a lot of time got to know that the **testing library** is not supporting shadow-dom which I found strange. As it is a dom testing library it should support all the dom.

Please help me to understand what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: should I mock the custom web component as per my need? is there any other solution for such scenario?

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/shadow-dom-testing-library

Comment: @possum tried this as well but I was able to achieve whatever this library is supporting without using it. did you try using this? does that resolve you scenarios?