# React testing library: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'disabled')]

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I am trying to write a test case for the back button which does a history push to the respective page.
However, facing some weird Typeerror with my test case which I am not able to understand why.
The error occurs when I try to click on the button. I also tried adding await on userEvent click
Below is the snippet which I tried.

```
  it("check cancel button redirect to internal tool page", async () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Order3DMaps />);
    const cancelButton = getByText("Cancel");
    cancelButton.onclick = mockFn;
    expect(cancelButton).toBeInTheDocument();
    await userEvent.click(cancelButton);
  });
```

I also tried getting the button from the screen with testId but that also didn't work. The idea here is to get the userEvent click works. if I remove the userEvent.click things work fine but as I skip that my code coverage will be less. Would highly appreciate it if someone can help me to understand the missing piece
Thanks

Comment: Can we get some more info about the component structure that you are trying to create the test for? I'm under the assumption that `Order3DMaps` has a disabled property that might need to be set or something.

Comment: I don't think this error has to do with your test, I think it's a problem in the component you are trying to render. That component must have somewhere - `something.disabled` and that `something` is null so you get an error because `.disabled` can't be accessed. Try adding optional chaining to allow `something` to be set without throwing an error before it does `something?.disalbed`

Comment: Hi @AviCohenNehemia seems there is some issue with my custom element. we have our own web component and in my case, the custom-button element which has some disabled property that is not under my control is having some issues. I am already struggling to write a test case for shadow dom and raised a question for help. I would love to get your thoughts on the below link as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74929633/testing-form-fields-as-a-shadow-dom-elements-with-react-testing-library-and-jest

Comment: @Nikster I would like to get your thoughts as well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using react-native-testing library.

In my case, it was just a wrong import of the component I wanted to test.

For example:

I put:

```
(Eslint automatic fix)
import PrimaryButton from "..";
```

Correct way:

```
import PrimaryButton from "../index"; or
import PrimaryButton from "../";
```